# Can I assign a CSS variable to another?

Tags: css, css-variables

Can I assign one globally defined CSS variable to another locally define variable?

For example, the variable `--dark` has been globally defined as `black`.

Then, I want to be able to do:

```
:root {
    --background-color: --dark
}

.light {
    --background-color: white
}

div {
   background-color: --background-color
}
```

So that by default, my `div` will have a black background. And when the class `light` is added to it, it will have a white background.

I need the 'default' `--dark` variable here because it is a theme variable.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You should assign as `var(--dark)`

```css
:root {
    --dark : black;
    --background-color: var(--dark);
}

.light {
    --background-color: white;
}

div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: var(--background-color);
}
```

```html
<div class="light"></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: And for Ionic, instead of `:root`, use `:host`. Thats where I was going wrong!